# Use WebRTC Voice Activity Detector (VAD) on live audio coming from VOIP streamed by Websockets

Tags: python, websocket, webrtc, voip, live-streaming

I'm trying to set up WebRTC Voice Activity Detector (VAD) for a VOIP call that is streaming through a websocket, to detect when the caller has stopped talking.

Most of the tutorials and questions around WebRTC VAD were based on recorded audio files, and not on a live stream. I would like to know how to implement it on a websocket streaming a VOIP call in real time.

According to the py-webrtcvad documentation (https://pypi.org/project/webrtcvad/):

> Give it a short segment (“frame”) of audio. The WebRTC VAD only accepts 16-bit mono PCM audio, sampled at 8000, 16000, or 32000 Hz. A frame must be either 10, 20, or 30 ms in duration

How would one go about converting a raw audio stream coming from the websocket to the requirements needed above by the WebRTC VAD to work?

Comment: What is the sample rate, bitdepth, and channel number of the raw audio you have coming from the websocket? And how big are the chunks coming from the websocket?

Answer (score 2):

To use VAD, you need chunk size correctly.
https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/issues/30

```
- For example, if your sample rate is 16000 Hz, then the only allowed 
frame/chunk sizes are: 
    16000 * ({10,20,30} / 1000) = 160, 320 or 480 samples.
- Since each sample is 2 bytes (16 bits), the only allowed frame/chunk sizes are 
320, 640, or 960 bytes.
```